# How to detect when all animations have stopped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using this code to stop simultaneous animations on 2  elements:

```
$('#container').find('*').stop(true, true);
```

The animation can be stopped by an end user hovering over a button, in which case the animation stops after completion (which is what I want).  However, the button hover also initiates another function (removes and reloads the  elements), and there's a conflict if that function runs before the animations are complete.

I was thinking that using 'after' or 'complete' with the above code might work, but I can't figure out what the syntax would be.

Comment: Try adding the hover handler only after the animation is completed. You need to show us more code and describe the conflict more if you want good answers.

Comment: @Spokey: Good idea about the hover handler.  I just needed to add a Boolean in the 'after' event of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you are trying to achieve, but in order to check whether or not there are running/pending animations on the object using jQuery, you can use  **[.promise().done()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)**

example, somehing of this sort:

```
var animations_running;

$('#container').promise().done(function() {
    animations_running=false;
});

$('#container').on("mouseover",".SomethingInside",function(){
    if(animations_running==false){
        //...do animations...
        animations_running=true;
    }
});
```

you can also add a callback function to your jQuery animations as follows:

```
$('#container').on("mouseover",".SomethingInside",function(){
    if(animations_running==false){
        $(this).animate({
            left:+=50
        },500,function(){
            //...this is the callback function...
        });
        animations_running=true;
    }
});
```